# Travel from the United States to Faroe Islands

Tags: denmark, faroe-islands

The Faroe Islands opened travel for holiday in April 2021.  As long as one is vaccinated, there is no quarantine requirement, but still have to be tested for Covid prior to leaving and when you land.  However, the travel rules for Denmark seem to be in contradiction to that of the Faroe Islands.  If I were to travel through (transit) Copenhagen, the Danish government says I can travel on holiday through the airport, but not to the Faroe Islands.  This doesn't make sense to me since the Faroese police have already informed me that I could go on holiday there, but the Danish government won't let me transit through the Copenhagen airport, even though you can transit through on holiday as long as it is not the Faroe Islands or Greenland.  Has anyone experienced traveling through Denmark to get to the Faroe Islands and was there a problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find your information about the transit restrictions?  According to [this website from the Danish Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/coronavirus-covid-19/), under the question "Can a foreign national travel through Denmark in transit to a final destination?":  "You can travel through Denmark (transit) to a destination outside of Denmark, **including the Faroe Islands and Greenland.** ... However, you are required to present a negative COVID-19 test taken no more than 48 hours before boarding the plane. "

Comment: @MichaelSeifert there's some ambiguity there, depending how you parse the sentence. Does "a destination outside of Denmark, including the Faroe Islands and Greenland" mean Faroes and Greenland are included as "outside of Denmark", or must the destination be outside of "Denmark, including the Faroe Islands and Greenland"? [This page](https://en.coronasmitte.dk/rules-and-regulations/entry-into-denmark/persons-in-transit) seems less ambiguous, and (unfortunately for OP) it appears that the second meaning is the intended one.

Comment: as for OP: I agree the rules seem to say you can't do this, but I don't see how it's a contradiction. Have you considered other routes to the Faroes? In normal times there are some flights from Norway, Iceland, and the UK. The airport website currently shows flights to and from Bergen and Trondheim in the next few days so it seems that at least some flights from Norway are still operating. Ferries from Iceland are also an option in theory, although I can't immediately see any information on the website as to whether they're currently operating.

Comment: Don't fly through Denmark? There at least also Norwegian flights. See https://www.fae.fo/ and https://www.visitfaroeislands.com/plan-your-stay/transport/getting-to-the-faroe-islands/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over